# VueJS Syntax: Running method on mount

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to load some data with `vue-resource` when a page loads, then re-load that data if a refresh button is pressed.

To keep my code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) I wanted to put this functionality in a method. This was my first attempt:

index.html:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

app.js:

```
const Vue = window.Vue = require("vue");
require("vue-resource");
const App = require("./components/App.vue");

window.app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

components/app.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>{text}</p>
        <button @click="loadData">Reload</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    // This fails
    mounted: this.loadData,
    methods: {
        loadData() {
            // This syntax may be wrong, too. But the function isn't
            // even running, so I haven't started to debug this yet
            this.$http.get("https://icanhazip.com")
                .then(xhr => this.text = xhr.body);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

This throws an error on line 10 of `components/app.vue`:

```
    mounted: this.loadData,
```

Saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reloadData' of undefined`

How can I get the `mounted` function to refer to any of the methods defined in `methods`?

Comment: BTW: `vue-resource` isn't really a thing anymore. https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `mounted` event in following way with correct method declaration.

```
export default {        
    mounted() {
      this.loadData();
    },
    methods: {
        loadData() {
            // This syntax may be wrong, too. But the function isn't
            // even running, so I haven't started to debug this yet
            this.$http.get("https://icanhazip.com")
                .then(xhr => this.text = xhr.body);
        }
    }
};
```

More details can be found here.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the v-on ( @ ) directive to listen to DOM events like click and run some function in methods in this way:

```
<button @click="loadData">Reload</button>
```

@Thusitha is correct for the mounted, you need to update it.

Comment: +1 because this pointed out a valid issue, but can't accept since it doesn't actually answer the original question.