# VueJS Syntax: Saving a value in a Promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

With [some help from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427612/vuejs-syntax-running-method-on-mount) I got the following to run my `loadData` when the page loads and when the button is clicked.

However the text on the page is not updating. Something is wrong about my syntax with `this.text = xhr.data`

```
index.html:

<div id="app"></div>

app.js:

const Vue = window.Vue = require("vue");
Vue.prototype.$http = require("axios");
const App = require("./components/App.vue");

window.app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    render: h => h(App)
});

components/app.vue:

<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>{{text}}</p>
        <button @click="this.loadData">Reload</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.loadData();
    },
    methods: {
        loadData() {
            this.$http.get("https://icanhazip.com")
                // This fails
                .then(xhr => this.text = xhr.data);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a data object. Only properties in the data object are reactive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must to define your text property in components data.

From Vue.js documentation:

Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive. For example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1
  }
})
// `vm.a` is now reactive
vm.b = 2
// `vm.b` is NOT reactive
```

In your case your component should look like this:

```
<script>
export default {
    created() {
        this.loadData();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            text: '',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        loadData() {
            this.$http.get("https://icanhazip.com")
                // This fails
                .then(xhr => this.text = xhr.data);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```